# Linux filebeat input collector for Graylog

Tags: filebeat, graylog2, graylog, graylog3

I'm try to configure a Graylog collector [filebeat] for Liunx. The part that I'm having an issue with is the paths:

The path I want to collect logs from has many log files contained in it. I only want to collect the files that have the format (example) 20201020.catalina.out

from a the command line I run this and it works on the server:

```
vi /var/log/oscar/`(date +"%Y%m%d.catalina.out")`
```

Bring up the file with today's date.

Example of my filebeat config:

```
> # Needed for Graylog fields_under_root: true fields.collector_node_id: ${sidecar.nodeName} fields.gl2_source_collector: ${sidecar.nodeId}
> 
> filebeat.inputs:
> - input_type: log
> 
>   paths:
>     
>     - /var/log/oscar/error-ssl.log
>     - /var/log/oscar/access-ssl.log
>     - /var/log/oscar/`(date +"%Y%m%d.catalina.out")`
```

When the collector is running it only captures only the  error-ssl.log and access-ssl.log [logs]

Answer (score 0):

Filebeat's [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-filebeat-options.html) says that "All patterns supported by Go Glob are also supported here."

And Go Glob's [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) says "the syntax of patterns is the same as in Match".

Finally, Match's [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) shows the supported pattern:

```
The pattern syntax is:

pattern:
    { term }
term:
    '*'         matches any sequence of non-Separator characters
    '?'         matches any single non-Separator character
    '[' [ '^' ] { character-range } ']'
                character class (must be non-empty)
    c           matches character c (c != '*', '?', '\\', '[')
    '\\' c      matches character c

character-range:
    c           matches character c (c != '\\', '-', ']')
    '\\' c      matches character c
    lo '-' hi   matches character c for lo <= c <= hi
```

So, you have to deal with this pattern. Something like this should work:

```
     - /var/log/oscar/*.catalina.out
```

Comment: Yes, that's correct but it will also read all the other files that are in that directory. There are archived .catalina files with date timestamp that I cannot remove from this directory. I want to ignore those files and only read the catalina.out file with the current date timestamp on the file.